# Kotlin database if child is null

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I want to call a function where drawableprofile is binding as a profile icon. I want to call it when "imageUrl" child doesn't exist.

```
val uid = firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid

if (uid != null) {
    database.child(uid).get().addOnSuccessListener {
        if (it.exists()) {
            val fetchimg = it.child("imageUrl").value
            Glide.with(this).load(fetchimg).into(binding.profileIcon)
        } else if {
            database.child(uid).child("imageUrl")
            val drawableprofile = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_person)
           
            Glide.with(this).load(drawableprofile).into(binding.profileIcon)
        }
    }
}
```

I can't find any .isNull function etc. Thanks for help

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what "call a function where drawableprofile is binding as profileIcon" means. Can you please be more specific? Or provide an example?

Comment: Besides that, what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: So in my app you can change profile image and this goes to imageUrl in database. Profile image is a clickable intent to another activity. Problem is when no profile image has been chosen yet, imageView doesn't show anything. There's no imageUrl so glide loads nothing.

I need to do a placeholder until a user choses his own profile image.

Comment: You need to parse the url you can easily do it with Glide or picasso or do it manually like  val fetching = java.net.URL(it.child("imageUrl").value).openStream()         
binding.profileIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fetching)

Answer (score 0):

According to your last comment:

> I need to do a placeholder until a user chooses his own profile image.

Since you're using Glide for Android to display your images, then you can simply call Glide#placeholder() like this:

```
Glide
    .with(this)
    .load(fetchimg) //
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_person)
    .into(binding.profileIcon);
```

Comment: Hey Kacper. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with the following:

```
val uid = firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid
if (uid != null) {
    val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                val imageUrl = snapshot.getValue<String>()
                if (imageUrl != null) {
                    Glide.with(this).load(imageUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_person).into(binding.profileIcon)
                    return
                }
                Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.ic_profile).into(binding.profileIcon)
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d("TAG", "onCancelled: ${error.message}")
            }
        }
        database.child(uid).addValueEventListener(valueEventListener)
    }
}
```